# Do an action when clicking on self

Tags: jquery, css

I'm stuck with a little problem, i can make the action of changing my img src AND remove my img class when i'm clicking a second time on the .lst-cours. Anybody know what i'm doing wrong ?

```
$('.lst-cours').click(function(){
  $(this).siblings('div').slideUp().css('border-top','0px solid #000')
  $('img.imgactiv').attr('src', 'images/fleche-form-debout.png').removeClass('imgactiv')
  $(this).css('border-top','1px solid #000')
  $('.active').removeClass('active')
  $(this).addClass('active')
  $('img', this).attr('src', 'images/fleche-form.png').addClass('imgactiv');
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/R6X4d/1/

Comment: You haven't explained the problem.

Comment: Seeing your HTML would help us help you!

Comment: I have put a jsfiddle, look the behavior of the arrow if you click twice on "Métier et formation"